# Group by percentage of total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a SQL Table with a column of Items which I want to display the percentage of the total counts of each item in desc order.

For example

```
Column A
Item 1
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

I would like to display:

```
Column A
Item 1   0.5
Item 2   0.25
Item 3   0.25
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
SELECT [Column A], (count([Column A]) / count(*))
  FROM [table]
  GROUP BY [Column A]
  Order by (count([Column A]) / count(*)) DESC
```

However, everything comes back as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `COUNT` group by `[Column A]` colunm in main query. then make total `count` in subquery do division.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   [Column A] VARCHAR(50)
); 

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 2');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 3');

SELECT [Column A],COUNT(*) /CAST ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T) AS FLOAT)
FROM T 
GROUP BY [Column A]
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f978cd4e174c54be78b2a122cc1b1cce)

Or you can use `CROSS JOIN` get the total then do division.

```
SELECT [Column A],COUNT(*) /CAST(total AS FLOAT)
FROM T CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM T) v
GROUP BY [Column A],total
```

Comment: That seemed to work.  I had a question about the second solution though.  Why is the v necessary for the query?

Comment: @notlaughing `v` is the alias name for the result set `(SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM T) `

Answer (score 1):

I think Window functions are a better solution for this kind of case because the table is read once.

If instead of a single percentage you have to create a percentage, an average, and a sum? Or the query is more complex than a single count? Creating many subqueries is not an option. So, this is the reason I prefer to use window functions rather than subqueries.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4f8719bf9e87b53d2849b4c5512296f)

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   [Column A] VARCHAR(50)
); 

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 2');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Item 3');

SELECT
   [Column A], CNT / SUM(CNT) OVER () PERC
FROM (
  SELECT [Column A], CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC) CNT
  FROM T 
  GROUP BY [Column A]
) X
ORDER BY PERC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your aggregate is applied on the grouped column regardless, you will need to get the total separately in some way. One way would be to use a derived table as with @D-Shih. I am just going to store it in a variable.

The other problem you have is that both your operands are INT therefor SQL Server is inferring the datatype of INT for the result. you just need one of operands to not return an integer datatype. I have used an exact numeric datatype because approximate numeric's could cause problems if later you need to sum the individual % to get 100%.

```
DECLARE @t_item TABLE
(       name VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @total_count NUMERIC(3,2)

INSERT INTO @t_item
VALUES ('ITEM1'),
       ('ITEM1'),
       ('ITEM2'),
       ('ITEM3'),
       ('ITEM3'),
       ('ITEM1')

SELECT @total_count = COUNT(*) FROM @t_item

SELECT name,
       COUNT(name),
       COUNT(*),
       pct_of_all      = CONVERT(NUMERIC(3,2),COUNT(name))/CONVERT(NUMERIC(3,2),COUNT(*))
  FROM @t_item
 GROUP BY name


SELECT name,
       COUNT(name),
       @total_count,
       pct_of_all      = COUNT(name)/@total_count
  FROM @t_item
 GROUP BY name
```